# Codility CyclicRotation Javascript Solution: Empty array returns an error

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, rotation

I am trying to solve [this problem](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training9DVHJQ-JAX/) in codility. My solution passed all the tests except for one with empty array and rotation of 1 as arguments. I'm someway lost of how to even approach for solving this issue. Could someone please nudge me in the right direction? Other than writing a specific `if` clause for an empty array check. I cannot come up with a more elegant solution.

```
function solution(A, K)
{
    for (i=0; i<K; i++)
    {
        A.unshift(A.pop());
    }
    return A;
}
```

Comment: I think you should check if the array is not empty as it said and if so, return the array empty itself. Why exactly you don't want to use `if statement`?

Comment: I guess I tend to overthink since I'm a novice. Would such a solution be acceptable in the world of professional development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to check for `A.length` on the loop `conditions` section.

```js
function solution(A, K)
{
    for (i = 0; i < K && A.length; i++)
    {
        A.unshift(A.pop());
    }
    return A;
}

console.log(solution([3, 8, 9, 7, 6], 3));
console.log(solution([], 5));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, there is an alternative approach you can do using [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
function solution(A, K)
{
    let i = A.length - (K % (A.length || 1));
    return [...A.slice(i), ...A.slice(0, i)];
}

console.log(solution([3, 8, 9, 7, 6], 3));
console.log(solution([], 0));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Oh i like this one

Comment: @NikaBo if this answers your question you should mark it as answered

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let solution = (A, K) => {
    for (i=0; i<K; i++){
        A.unshift(A.pop());
    }
    return A[0] != undefined ? A : [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to solve this could be via recursion. In this case, you can use an `if` statement, however, this serves as the base case for the termination of your recursive calls. The base case here is if `K === 0` meaning if we don't need to rotate the array anymore, then return the array. It also has another part where we return the array if `!A.length`. This means that if the array is empty also return the current array.

```js
function solution(A, K) {
  if(K === 0 || !A.length) return A;
  return solution([A.pop(), ...A], K-1);  
}

console.log(solution([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)); // [3, 4, 1, 2]
console.log(solution([], 10)); // []
```

The above can be rewritten as a one-liner if you wish:

```
const f = (A, K) => K === 0 || !A.length ? A : f([A.pop(), ...A], K-1);
```

You can visualize the function above performing the following (let the function `solution` be `f` for our example):

```
f([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) = f([4] + [1, 2, 3], 1) = f([4, 1, 2, 3], 1)

f([4, 1, 2, 3], 1) = f([3, 4, 1, 2], 0) --> [3, 4, 1, 2] // we return the array instead of another function call as K === 0 (our base case)
```

Or when the array is empty:

```
f([], 10) = [] // instantly return our array as it is empty. The clause !A.length is true (also part of our base case) which means we return A (our array) instantly.
```

Comment: Nice recursive approach and explanation, +1! However, I don't know if the OP will understand this way.

Comment: @Shidersz thanks :) yeah I agree, it may be a little difficult to understand if the OP hasn't seen recursion before. I suppose this is just another way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: I am familiar with recursion but it's definitely not my strong suite. I will have to chew on this answer for a while to make sure I understand what is happening here. I appreciate the challenge

Comment: @NikaBo recursion can be difficult to wrap your head around. It really just takes practice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that got 100% across the board:

```
function solution(A, K) {
    const k = K % A.length; // in case the rotation is bigger than the length of the array
    if (K === 0 || k === 0) {
      return A;
    }
    const head = A.slice(0, A.length - k);
    const tail = A.slice(A.length - k, A.length);
    return [...tail, ...head];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got 100%.

```
function cyclicRotation(A, K){
    K = K % A.length
    let sliceA = A.slice(A.length-K, A.length)
    let sliceB = A.slice(0, A.length-K)
    return sliceA.concat(sliceB)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My 100% JavaScript solution that avoids changing the value of *A* parameter by creating a copy of *A* beforehand:

```
function solution(A, K) {

    const rotatedA = [...A];

    for (let i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        rotatedA.length > 0 && rotatedA.unshift(rotatedA.pop());
    }

    return rotatedA;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got 100%, please give me your opinion

```
function solution(A, K) {
    let returnedArray = [...A];
    if((A.length === K || A.length === 0 || isAllValueTheSame(A))){
        return A
    }
    for(let i = 0;i<K;i++){
        returnedArray = rotate(returnedArray)
    }
    return returnedArray
}

function isAllValueTheSame (A){
    const firstValue = A[0]
    return A.every((value) => value === firstValue)
}

function rotate (A){
    let tempArray = [...A];
    tempArray[0] = A[A.length-1] // the last goes first
    for(let i = 0 ; i < A.length -1 ;i++){
        tempArray[i+1] = A[i]
    }
    return tempArray
}
```